# The thread 0x798 has exited with code 0 (0x0)

Tags: .net

I'm trying to run my project in visual web developer 2008 but I am getting these logs from the Output of the web developer.

'WebDev.WebServer.EXE' (Managed): Loaded 'C:\Windows\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Web.Extensions\3.5.0.0__31bf3856ad364e35\System.Web.Extensions.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.

The thread 0xef4 has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0xb3c has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 0x17a0 has exited with code 0 (0x0).

At first, my web browser prompts and then it will load some of the web page components then after a minute, the error above will appear on my visual web developer and when I'm going back to the web browser, it now displays "This page is not available".

I am not getting any error from the visual web developer so I am having a hard time debugging the project.  Any ideas where to look at?

Thanks.